# find the width of the image surrounded by black region:Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image image1, it is surrounded by black region.

I want to get width of the region which is not black i.e. the image inside the Black region only.

how to do this?

Comment: Is it completely black (equal to zero) or just approximately?

Comment: it is equal to zero.completely black

Answer (score 1):

If it's completely black, you can just count the number of column which have at least one non-zero element:

```
sum(any(image1))
```